# If $\frac{a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2}{3} \in R$, then $a\equiv b \equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod3$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $\frac{a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2}{3} \in R$, then $a\equiv b \equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod3$

where $R=\mathcal{O}\cap\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$

I know that if $\frac{a+b\alpha}{3}$, then $a\equiv b \equiv 0 \pmod3$.

Then $\frac{a+b\alpha}{3}$ + $\frac{c\alpha^2}{3} $ $\in R$ $\Rightarrow$ $c\equiv 0 \pmod3$

is it correct?

Comment: This is immediate if you know $ R = \Bbb Z + \alpha \Bbb Z + \alpha^2 \Bbb Z.$ What is $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha= \sqrt[3]{2}$

Comment: It would be easier to read your question, if you begin by telling the reader what $\alpha$ is. It would not hurt to tell what $R$ and $\mathcal{O}$ are either :-). We can guess, but it surely isn't to your advantage to make people (who want to help you) waste their energy guessing!

Comment: But your argument does not work. The reason is that even though $(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2)/3\in R$, you cannot conclude that $(a+b\alpha)/3\in R$.

Comment: I'm sure this is done in many a book. There are probably shortcuts, but here's a way you can brute force it. The characteristic polynomial of $z=(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2)/3$ is
$$M(x)=x^3-ax^2+\frac{a^2-2bc}3x+\frac{4c^3+6abc+2b^3-a^3}{27}.$$ We are to prove that if its coefficients are integers, then $a,b,c$ are all divisible by three. Because $z$ is an algebraic integer whenever $z-(k+\ell\alpha+m\alpha^2), k,\ell,m\in\Bbb{Z},$ is an integer, you can assume that $a,b,c\in\{0,1,2\}$. That's 27 cases to be checked. It is easy to see that if one of them is 0, the others must be, too. Eight cases...

Answer (score 3):

What's $\alpha$?

The claim is not true in general.  For example if $\alpha = \root 3 \of {10}$
then $(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)/3$ is an algebraic integer, namely a root of
$x^3-x^2-3x-3$.